# Index numbers of outer branches of a symmetric network in Python

Tags: python, networking

I want to generate index numbers of outer horizontal and vertical branches of a symmetric network. The numbers on the figure represent the index.

For Fig `I`, the output should be `H - {0,1},{10,11}`, `V - {2,7},{4,9}` where `H` and `V` stand for outer horizontal and outer vertical branches respectively.

Similarly, for fig `II`, the output should be `H - {0,1,2},{21,22,23}`, `V - {3,10,17},{6,13,20}`.

[image]

Comment: What data format are the networks in originally? Or are you just asking about the identifiers of a generic n x m network? (or n x n, as you're asking about symmetric networks)

Comment: I am just looking to identify for a generic ```nxn``` network using the notation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any n * n network:

- the indices across the top will always be `range(n-1)`
- the indices across the bottom similarly `range((2*n-1)*(n-1), 2*n*(n-1))`
- the indices on the left are `range(n-1, (2*n-1)*(n-2)+n, 2*n-1)`
- and on the right `range(2*n-2, (2*n-1)*(n-2)+2*n-1, 2*n-1)`

So, in code:

```
def hv(n):
    return (
        (
            tuple(range(n-1)), 
            tuple(range((2*n-1)*(n-1), 2*n*(n-1))
        ),
        (
            tuple(range(n-1, (2*n-1)*(n-2)+n, 2*n-1), 
            tuple(range(2*n-2, (2*n-1)*(n-2)+2*n-1, 2*n-1)
        )
    )


print(hv(4))
```

Output:

```
(((0, 1, 2), (21, 22, 23)), ((3, 10, 17), (6, 13, 20)))
```

Maybe with some algebra, you could simplify some more.